# Problema con la opción `predict` en R - Studio

Tags: r

buenos días.

Cree el código (entre otros muchos) que sigue abajo, pero no consigo que la predicción empiece en el mes de octubre en vez de en enero. Por favor, ¿qué estoy haciendo mal?

gracias y un saludo

```
fecha <- as.Date(c("2015-01-28", "2015-02-04","2015-03-25", "2015-04-07", "2015-05-27", "2015-06-15", "2015-07-21", "2015-08-26", "2015-09-18", "2015-10-28", "2015-11-11", "2015-12-28", "2016-01-27", "2016-02-25", "2016-03-21", "2016-04-13", "2016-05-03", "2016-06-28", "2016-07-27", "2016-08-26", "2016-09-28"))

importe <- as.numeric(c(38482329.42, 40170005.73, 39573901.41, 38194584.46, 41308008.57, 39286280.41, 39140885.40, 40131789.82, 41331386.52, 41388516.82, 39467688.74, 40413666.02, 38601205.36, 40969065.69, 39963439.96, 39183362.01, 39445567.03, 38392694.62, 43295992.07, 45414800.06, 47209602.20))

com = data.frame(fecha, importe)

modelo1=HoltWinters(ts(com, frequency = 12))
cas=predict(modelo1,12)

cas

       Jan      Feb      Mar      Apr      May      Jun      Jul      Aug      Sep
4                                                       55917454 56425608 56933750
5 58966358 59474506 59982650 58888074 56120458 53307399                           
       Oct      Nov      Dec
4 57441909 57950043 58458210
5
```

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar no es necesario indicar explicitamente las fechas en donde se midió cada valor. Cuando creás la serie de tiempo la función ts lo calcula de forma automática si indicás la frecuencia y el inicio de las mediciones.

Si transformás el dataframe **com** de la siguiente forma a una serie de tiempo y lo graficás vas a ver el problema:

```
com_ts <- ts(com)
plot(com_ts)
```

[image: grafico serie de tiempo]

Por otro lado si mirás lo valores de la serie de tiempo vas a ver que la fecha te lo convirtió a un valor numerico y lo trata como una serie de tiempo algo que no tiene sentido.

```
com_ts
```

Para solucionar esto tenés que proceder de la siguiente forma:

```
importe <- c(38482329.42, 40170005.73, 39573901.41, 38194584.46, 41308008.57, 39286280.41, 39140885.40, 40131789.82, 41331386.52, 41388516.82, 39467688.74, 40413666.02, 38601205.36, 40969065.69, 39963439.96, 39183362.01, 39445567.03, 38392694.62, 43295992.07, 45414800.06, 47209602.20) #no es necesario as.numeric

com_ts <- ts(importe, frequency = 12, start = c(2015,1))
```

Ahora aplicamos la función HoltWinters

```
> modelo1 <- HoltWinters(com_ts)
Error in decompose(ts(x[1L:wind], start = start(x), frequency = f), seasonal) : 
  time series has no or less than 2 periods
```

Este error se debe a que necesitás al menos 2 periodos y el segundo se encuentra incompleto. Así que vas a tener que usar un modelo no estacionario haciendo gamma = FALSE.

```
modelo1 <- HoltWinters(com_ts, gamma = FALSE)
plot(modelo1)
```

[image: grafico modelo]

Y finalmente ya podés predecir y graficar.

```
cas <- predict(modelo1,3) #Predecir los siguientes 3 meses
> cas
          Oct      Nov      Dec
2016 48968050 50902104 52836158

plot(modelo1, cas)
```

[image: grafico de predicciones]

Los años están en decimal por un tema de configuración en mi ambiente.

Comment: funciona perfectamente, eres un genio